# Return username of the user who just logged in within a login script

Tags: osx

I'm writing a login script for OSX 10.8.

I need to know the name of the user who logged in via the Login Window within a login script.

I've tried "whoami", "$USER", and "ls -l /dev/console | awk '{print $3}'", but they all return "root".  I assume this is because login scripts run as root, not as the user who authenticated at the Login Window.

Here's an example:

If I login as "bob", or "john", I want the to be able to set a variable to "bob", or "john".

Comment: Can you post output what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using login hooks then the current user should be getting passed as the first parameter to your script. Try $1.

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you not want to be using loginhooks for this?

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2181368?start=0&tstart=0

*excerpt of that thread*

> loginhook
>
> This is a place where you can attach a script as the user logs in. You
>   are still the root user for the duration of the script, but
>   immediately after the script ends you become the logging-in user.
>
> [HT2420- Mac OS X: Creating a login hook](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420)